# Capitalize letters added after the year in twin bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

When using more than 1 references that have the same author and created in the same year, usually the references are sorted by title and a letter is added after the year to differentiate them in citations.

For example, here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            bibstyle=authoryear,
            citestyle=authoryear,
            sorting=nyt,
            dashed=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{myref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{myref.bib}
@inproceedings{someone:2000:xx,
    author = {Some Researcher},
    title = {Some Important Paper},
    year = {2000},
    booktitle = {Proc. of Some Cool Conference},
    pages = {123--126}
}

@inproceedings{someone:2000:yy,
    author = {Some Researcher},
    title = {Some Other Important Paper},
    year = {2000},
    booktitle = {Proc. of Some Other Cool Conference},
    pages = {123--126}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{someone:2000:xx}
\cite{someone:2000:yy}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

it appears in my bibliography like this:

[image: my bibliography]

I would like the letters after years to be capitalized so it will be (2000A) and (2000B) instead of (2000a) and (2000b) because that's my thesis format as written in the guidelines. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal working example (MWE) instead of just code snippets. The example should be complete (i.e. compilable as is; it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`) and only contain what's necessary to reproduce your problem. ([Here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/48973)'s an example of how to do that with a bibliography.) This makes it easier for us to reproduce your problem and test our solutions.

Comment: As a side note: any reason why you are using `bibtex` instead of the preferred `biber`?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment. I've replaced the code snippets with an MWE. As for why I'm using `bibtex` and not `biber`, well, to be honest I'm currently using a template which was used by my seniors in previous years, so I just kinda stick with it. But the rules/writing format has changed since then and I had to do minor revisions myself hence this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the extra letter is controlled by the `extradate` field format. By default it uses `\mknumalph`, which produces a small Latin letter from a given number. We can copy the definition of `\mknumalph` to get a `\mknumAlph` which produces capital Latin letters and use that in the format.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{%
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
    {\mknumAlph{#1}}
    {\mkbibparens{\mknumAlph{#1}}}}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\mknumAlph}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@tempcnta=#1\relax
  \ifnum\blx@tempcnta>702 %
  \else
    \ifnum\blx@tempcnta>26 %
      \advance\blx@tempcnta\m@ne
      \divide\blx@tempcnta26\relax
      \blx@numalph\blx@tempcnta
      \multiply\blx@tempcnta26\relax
      \blx@tempcnta=\numexpr#1-\blx@tempcnta\relax
    \fi
  \fi
  \blx@numAlph\blx@tempcnta
  \endgroup}
\def\blx@numAlph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\blx@warning@entry{Value out of range}\number#1\or
  A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J\or K\or L\or M\or
  N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T\or U\or V\or W\or X\or Y\or Z\else
  \blx@warning@entry{Value out of range}\number#1\fi}
\makeatother


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Knuth 1986A; Knuth 1986B)]

---

For a shorter implementation of `\mknumAlph` you can use `expl3`

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mknumAlph}{m}{\int_to_Alph:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Or also `\makeatletter\newcommand[\mknumAlph}[1]{\@Alph{#1}}\makeatother`, assuming that there are no more than 26 entries with the same year. However this could conflict with some `babel` modules that do devious things to `\@Alph`.